# asp.net context menu

Tags: asp.net

I want to display the context menu on right click of link button in asp.net. I want this in javascript.

I could find javascript event of right click.

Can anybody help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://deluxe-menu.com/popup-mode-sample.html